# Windows 8.1's audio service chokes on threads and handles?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, hibernate, threads

-- snipped as the hibernation thing seems to be invalid now --

**Edit**: I found this...
[image]
This process is using 52,552 handles and 6,065 threads when I took the screenshot.
At the time of writing, 52,913 threads and 6,111 threads.
[image]
I can't find any connection between the sounds and that service's handle/thread usage.
I use Spotify most of the time, and events such as pausing/resuming or song switching doesn't seem to trigger any reaction in the service.

**Edit 2**: I found [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981013). I'll keep investigating.
My workaround so far was manually restarting the audio service.
It seems to trigger on every individual sound played... Wow...

**Edit 3**: Tried [this](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=HT069905). Will keep monitoring the process for a few days and report the result.

Comment: Also, I lack the means to test this on another edition/version of Windows, but I noticed a similar effect on Windows 7, after about a month of usage with nightly hibernations.

Comment: install the WPT and when you get the issue again, run this xommand to capture the slowness: http://pastebin.com/at7DyJxm

Comment: Oh Lord, that is going to be extremely difficult! I'll try to do it...

Comment: what is difficult? Install the tool or copy&paste the command text into a CMD.exe and run it?

Comment: run the command before you have the issue and use Taskmgr to set the priority of the CMD prompt to realtime. When you have the issue, capture 60s of the slowness and switch to the cmd and press a key. Does this work?

Comment: I'll try this ASAP. Right now, I kinda have to use the laptop. Got a school project that I need to take care of.

Comment: Added more useful information.

Comment: 9 hours later, I'm still down to 19-21 threads.

Comment: 10 threads... o.O

Comment: ok, so the disabling of the effects fixed it. This is a known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 days later, after a shutdown and numerous hibernations, the process is down to 300 handles and 5 threads. I call this a success!
This is the final workaround (honestly, it's not a solution) that worked: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=HT069905

I have a Lenovo laptop, but I see no reason why this wouldn't work on devices from other manufacturers, because the problem seems to be in the OS's service, not in a driver.